# Cannot conform to swift delegate protocol from objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, protocols

I'm using a swift pod in an objective C project.
I successfully access swift classes from objective-c, anyway I'm facing an issue to adopt swift protocol.
The compiler does not complain, generated bridging header seems correct.

Problem occurs at runtime when calling `[self.sceneLocationView setLocationNodeTouchDelegate: self];` that results in **[ARCL.SceneLocationView setLocationNodeTouchDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**.

I cannot find any solution to this issue, I spent time to search here, but still no luck to make this working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

My swift and objective-c files are shown below.

**SceneLocationView.swift:**

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
open class SceneLocationView: ARSCNView {
   ...
   @objc public weak var locationNodeTouchDelegate: LNTouchDelegate?
   ...
}
```

**SceneLocationViewDelegate.swift :**

```
@objc public protocol LNTouchDelegate: class {
    func locationNodeTouched(node: AnnotationNode)
}
```

**ViewController.h :**

```
#import "ARCL-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <LNTouchDelegate>{
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) SceneLocationView *sceneLocationView;
```

**ViewController.m :**

```
#import "ARCL-Swift.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.sceneLocationView = [[SceneLocationView alloc] init];
    [self.sceneLocationView run];
    [self.view addSubview: self.sceneLocationView];
    ...
    [self.sceneLocationView setLocationNodeTouchDelegate: self]; <-- ERROR HERE
}

-(void) locationNodeTouchedWithNode:(AnnotationNode *)node {
}
```

**ARCL-Swift.h :**

```
SWIFT_PROTOCOL("_TtP4ARCL15LNTouchDelegate_")
@protocol LNTouchDelegate
- (void)locationNodeTouchedWithNode:(AnnotationNode * _Nonnull)node;
@end

SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC4ARCL17SceneLocationView") SWIFT_AVAILABILITY(ios,introduced=11.0)
@interface SceneLocationView : ARSCNView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <LNTouchDelegate> _Nullable locationNodeTouchDelegate;
- (nonnull instancetype)init;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame options:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * _Nullable)options OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)aDecoder OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)layoutSubviews;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE;
@end
```

Comment: What happens if you just use simple assignment `self.sceneLocationView.locationNodeTouchDelegate = self;`?

Comment: same, this results in the same runtime error.

Comment: Works here. Tested with Xcode 11.2. I just used `SceneLocationView: UIView` for testing. It seems the reason is not in provided code.

Comment: Thanks for your test @Asperi, I'm using Xcode 10.2 as my mac is too old to install latest Xcode 11. Did you use swift 5 ? Xcode is asking me to convert from swift 4.2 to 5

Comment: Works as well with macOS 10.13.6 / Xcode 9 / Swift 4.0. I don't have in between those versions. It might be the reason in pod or project configurations, but definitely nothing wrong with Objective-C <> Swift bridge.